# Neo4j Temporal Query with NaT

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to do a temporal query similar to below:

```
MATCH (n:Event)
WHERE datetime(n.date) = datetime("2019-01-01")
RETURN n
```

But some `NaT` values have snuck into my `n.date` property. Is there any way to still do this query without having to update those nodes?

I can't remove the Date field from the nodes that have `NaT` as a value because the nature of the node the date is actually part of the node key.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

My bad.. didn't think to exclude `NaT` from the query.

```
MATCH (n:Event)
WHERE n.date <> "NaT" AND datetime(n.date) = datetime("2019-01-01")
RETURN n
```

Comment: Keep in mind that your query will not allow an index lookup (for an index on :Event(date)` since your query requires you to transform it using the `datetime()` function. If you're using a Neo4j version >= 3.4.x, then you can store native temporal types as properties. If you can do this for this property across all :Event nodes, you can take advantage of index lookups and speed up your related queries.